# Include JQuery and Bootstrap with CDN (integrity & crossorigin) error?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

as of this morning one of my applications was throwing an error on page load. After I opened developer tools there was an error message. Here is example:

```
None of the “sha384” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource.
```

I have tried clearing browser history then reloading the page but same error showed up. Then I tried different browser and same thing showed up. Here is my code example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">My WebPage</h1>
</div>


  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Everything worked just fine yesterday and as of this morning I'm having issues. I'm wondering if downloading jQuery and Bootstrap and load the files from local server will fix this? I heard that CDN is preferred but with this going on I am not sure.

Comment: If the libraries are critical for your applications to work, always serve them from your local server.  Or implement logic that will serve the files from local if they are not available from the CDN.

Comment: The issue is related to CDN. Loading the resource from the server is not actually a solution for the problem.